# Python sys.argv scoping rules

Tags: python

I just noticed sys.argv is visible in a imported script.

A.py

```
import sys
print("A")
print(sys.argv)
import B
```

B.py

```
import sys
print("B")
print(sys.argv)
```

Yields

```
>> python A.py --foo bar
>> A
>> ['path/to/A.py', '--foo', 'bar']
>> B
>> ['path/to/A.py', '--foo', 'bar']
```

This is nice since now I don't have to do the argument parsing in the main script (aka. manage.py).

The question is: can I rely on this behavior? Are there cases where this will not work?

Comment: I'd rather create an argument parsing function in a module and then call it from the main script, or even create it on the main script.

Comment: Well guys, you make it hard. You all answer some (sub) questions I had. Accept goes to unutbu for being the first, but thanks to you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Module attributes, like `sys.argv` are objects. It does not matter from which module you access them, they are the same object.

That also means if one module modifies `sys.argv`, then that change will also affect any other module that accesses `sys.argv`.

---

A tip regarding coding style:

Although it is *possible* to access `sys.argv` from two different modules, I wouldn't recommend it, and here's why.

I like scripts that can also double as modules. This gives you the greatest flexibility in reusing code. `sys.argv` is only meaningful when the code is called as a script. In order for code to be useful as a module, the code should not depend on looking up values in `sys.argv`.

Therefore, I would recommend parsing `sys.argv` *once* in the main calling script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    def parse_args():
        ... # argparse uses  sys.argv

    args = parse_args()
```

and then passing the values in `args` to functions as needed.

Thus, everything outside of the `if __name__ == 'main__'` statement need not depend on `sys.argv`, and can thus be used through simple function calls or module imports.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the scope of `sys.argv` specifically, it's that all modules are loaded in a single global instance.

So if `A.py` imports a module and then modifies it, if `B.py` imports that same module, it's just gaining access to the module `A.py` imported.

For example:

A.py

```
import sys
sys.foo = "foo!"
import B
```

B.py

```
import sys
print sys.foo
```

Running `A.py` here would import `B.py`, which would have access to the modified `sys` module and the `foo` variable inside of it. However, if you were to run B.py directly, this code would raise an error that `sys.foo` doesn't exist.

This is a very poor behavior to rely upon, as it makes very strong assumptions of which module imports which, and makes for extremely brittle code.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.argv` is set in `Modules/main.c` during startup (with the `PySys_SetArgv`) function.

Now, it *is* possible that another module also calls `PySys_SetArgv` or `PySys_SetArgvEx`, but none of the standard modules seem to do this (Python 2.7), and doing so would either 1) Be part of something *very* specific, or 2) Idiotic

So-called "argv clobbering" is sometimes used to set the process title, although modern systems provide better ways to do this, but since the values of the C `argv` are copied on startup, this shouldn't be a problem, even if it would be used.

So, yes. You can reasonably rely on `sys.argv`in all modules, although there are ways to break it, if you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

sys.argv is set when the parent script starts. No matter what you import, it is not going to be changed anywhere.